# Почему Ajax возвращает error?

Tags: ajax, node.js

Вот запрос Ajax, отправляю на ноду данные, serializeToJSON использую чтоб привести json в нужный мне вид

```
$('.btn-send').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let json = $('#form').serializeToJSON({
            associativeArrays: true,
        });
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'http://localhost:3000/',
            data:{
                items: json.Product
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
    });
```

Здесь пытаюсь вывести хоть что-то в success:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    getClick(req, res);
});

function getClick(req, res) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.send('Test message');
}
```

Почему-то Test message возвращается как error и в консоль прилетает это:

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function, …}
```

Там конечно содержится Test message, но не понимаю почему Ajax обрабатывает как error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res.send('Test message');
```

это не

```
dataType: 'JSON',
```

Отправьте

```
res.send('{"result":"success"}');
```

Comment: Спасибо, почему-то думал что 
`dataType: 'json' `
действует только на отправляемые данные

Comment: @JoelKamp Нет, это тип данных именно ответа. Успехов.

Comment: @JoelKamp, на отправляемые действует только `contentType`, а `dataType` - только на получаемые.